# Place Call Using Self-Managed ConnectionService Not Working on Samsung

Tags: android, voip, samsung-mobile

We are currently building a VOIP calling application with the intention of it primarily being used on Samsung tablets. However, we are having issues with one.

In total we have 4 Samsung tablets; SM-T395, SM-T390, SM-T590, and the SM-T290. Of these, we are only having issues with the SM-T290.

We have implemented a self-managed connection service as documented by google at - 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged

On the SM-T290 incoming connections work correctly, but when attempting to place an outgoing call using TelecomManager.placeCall(...), neither of the expected methods on my service are called.

onCreateOutgoingConnection(...) or onCreateOutgoingConnectionFailed(...)

Looking through an unfiltered logcat when using placeCall(...) We see the following on the devices.

SM-T395 (Working)
I/Telecom:SamsumgTelecomSystemManager: isVoiceCapable(internal) : true

SM-T390 (Working)
I/Telecom:SamsumgTelecomSystemManager: isVoiceCapable(internal) : false
I/Telecom:SamsumgCmcSystemListener: isVoiceCapable - isSdDevice : true

SM-T290 (Not Working)
I/Telecom:SamsumgTelecomSystemManager: isVoiceCapable(internal) : false
I/Telecom:SamsumgCmcSystemListener: isVoiceCapable - isSdDevice : false

On the working devices, there is more log output from calling classes that I have omitted. But on the non-working all call processing appears to cease.

To us it looks like voice calling is disabled on the SM-T290 and this is why the connection service method of calling fails. Is this correct?  And if so, can it be re-enabled?

Why does the SM-T590 work but SM-T290 does not? Both are wifi only, and have 1 speaker and microphone.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you find the solution? i encountered similar problem...

Comment: Looks like there is an open forum post here: https://forum.developer.samsung.com/t/self-managed-connectionservice-not-working/933 Not sure if that was you or not but no action on it in a while. I'm watching since I'm experiencing the same issue with the Tab SM-T510 device